# What is the correct way to manage memory in a media heavy swift app? Release it?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, parse-platform, uiimageview

UPDATE:
I fixed the memory leak. I am still very curious to hear what the best practices are for an app that is designed to pull down a potentially endless stream of image data to balance performance (user sees image without download delay) and memory usage.   I am also curious if anyone can speak to 1) is a PFFile just a path used to get the data in a stream or is each PFFile element taking up considerable space?  2) To release the space after an image has been viewed will setting the image=nil release the space?

EDITED ORIGINAL POST:
Is there a best practice for image heavy apps (an example would be facebook or instagram) where users can continually cycle through images.  I noticed that memory usage constantly increases using my current approach.

Currently I have a parse-server class for "Images" where the actual image is a PFFile.  I select * from this and read each row into an array of customer data struct containing the "Images" fields of which the PFFile is one.  I then maintain a "current Position" variable and each time the user clicks next I add one convert the PFFile at current position into a UIImage, set that in the array element, and update the image view (that way when they click back I don't have to reprocess the PFFile.  When testing my app I quickly saw the memory usage spike to 2gb since going through every image meant that every UIImage was retained in an array. I definitely think that I can NOT hold on to every UIImage since users may look at all the images and I will run out of memory.

I suspect that instead of retaining every UIImage after I convert the data I need to release the previous ones.  Generally I would appreciate any advice or direction for things that I can educate myself on to responsibly manage data when I am allowing users to scroll through an indeterminate number of images.

Comment: Are you using any libraries to handle image cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your memory isn't decreasing even after the view controller disappears then you have a memory problem somewhere. Maybe something else is referencing that array with images and causing it to not be released?

For your general problem, you need some way to save the images to a cache (on disk). Keeping an ever-growing array of UIImage objects will mean your app will be terminated. If you try testing on a device you'll find that 2GB of memory being used will cause the system to terminate your app. For caching use a library. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) is very popular.

Finally, pay attention to the system telling you about memory pressure with `UIViewController`'s `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and the `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification. When you get one of those notifications, release some of the images. How you should do this is complex and depends on your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I will research all those topics, as a general question, how do other apps do this. If you are on the photos section on Facebook or tinder you can scan infinitely for example, is there a best practice for that type of feature, perhaps the whole screen should be a collection view cell? Or maybe every time you go to next image I should nil out the downloaded data in the previous one? –

Comment: I would say those apps are using very complex caching but the general thing you should do is keep as few images in memory as possible. Tinder only needs the current image and the next image in memory. A `UITableView` has a kind of cache too. Look at the docs to see how they reuse cells. Any time a cell is reused any image it references will be released (as long as the image isn't referenced by something else)

Comment: to remove an image to memory do I just set it to nil?  Or is that not sufficient?  By any long shot do you understand how the parse server PFFile handles memory?  I assume that the PFFile when selected from the table is just a reference to the datastream and that no memory is consumed until you translate that into a UIImage, but I am wondering if perhaps the PFFile fills itself up with data and then reformats that into UIImage and thus I would have to nil that out somehow as well?

Comment: You have to make sure every reference to the image is set to nil. Have a look at the memory management docs to find out more. I'm afraid I don't know Parse at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to play with `@AUTORELEASEPOOL`. [Here](https://en.swifter.tips/autoreleasepool/) is a nice article by Wei Wang about it.

Hope it helps.